# Informix - Delete temp table if exists

Tags: sql, informix

I'm trying to delete a temp table when I run a query. I cannot find the answer and already searched for documentation.

Basically, what I want to do is check if a table exists; if it does exist, delete it and proceed with the select so that the results can be inserted into the temp table. If it doesn't exist, well, just create the TEMP table so that the results can be inserted.

I'm using Informix 11.70

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is supported in 11.70 (it is in 12.10), then the syntax is:

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_table_name;
```

The 11.70 manual for [DROP TABLE](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_11.70.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0736.htm?lang=en) indicates that it exists in 11.70 as well as 12.10.

Then run your query with the `INTO TEMP temp_table_name` clause to recreate the table.

Comment: Is this syntax supported in the .net provider?  I'm trying it against CSDK 4.10FC4 and IfxException: "ERROR [42000] [Informix .NET provider][Informix]A syntax error has occurred."

Comment: Most relevant is 'which version of Informix are you using as the database server?' The `IF EXISTS` notation was added in 11.70, so if you are using 11.50 or earlier, the server will not support the notation at all. I'd not expect there to be a specific problem with the .NET provider per se; I'd not expect it to be parsing and rejecting the syntax (that's the server's job, not a job for the client API). However, funnier things have been known, and CSDK 4.10.FC4 is normally associated with Informix 12.10 (nominally 12.10.FC4) servers, so I'm a little puzzled.

Comment: Oh, of course - that makes sense.  I checked the dev server I'm working with and it's 11.10.UC1, so that explains it.  I ran it against a 12.10FC8 server and it works as expected.

Comment: Great. I like simple solutions to problems like that.  I will observe that 11.10 has been out of service for a number of years as far as IBM is concerned.  Ideally, you should not be using it even for a development server.  It's more important that it is not used in production, though, but that isn't self-evidently a problem.

Answer (score 2):

you can also add an exception block such as:

```
Begin
    On Exception in (-206)
    End Exception with Resume;

    Drop table <<myTempTable>>;
End;
```